# File extractor brings all files instead of just zip file

Tags: c#, zip

I've created a file extractor, now it does work, however it also moves all the files from the `startDir` to the `destDir` along with, the zip file. How can I get this program to only move the zip file, instead of all the files?

Source:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ArchiveCreator
{
    class Program
    {
        //When program is run successfully this will be the output
        public string Success(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine(input);
            return input;
        }

        //When program encounters an error this will be the output
        public string Warn(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(input);
            return input;
        }

        //When program has information to show, this will be the output
        public string Say(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
            Console.WriteLine(input);
            return input;
        }

        //Main method
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //These variables are used to create a
            //random string that will be used as the
            //zip files name
            var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            var stringChars = new char[8];
            var random = new Random();

            //Info is used as provide the type of
            //information that will be displayed
            //by the program
            Program info = new Program();

            //Create the zip file name
            for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
            {
                stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
            }
            string finalString = new String(stringChars);

            info.Say("Starting file extraction..");

            string startDir = @"c:/users/thomas_j_perkins/test_folder";
            string destDir = @"c:/users/thomas_j_perkins/archive/";
            string zipName = $"c:/users/thomas_j_perkins/archive/{finalString}.zip";

            try
            {
                ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startDir, zipName);
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipName, destDir);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                info.Warn($"Error: {e}");
            }
            info.Success($"Extracted files successfully to: {destDir}");
            info.Say("Press enter to exit..");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Image of directory after program is run:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is creating a zip file in the destination directory when you call

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startDir, zipName);
```

The zipname path is in the destDir.  Did you mean to put it in the startDir?

string startDir = @"c:/users/thomas_j_perkins/test_folder";

string destDir = @"**c:/users/thomas_j_perkins/archive/**";

string zipName = $"**c:/users/thomas_j_perkins/archive/**{finalString}.zip";

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: When you call CreateFromDirectory, you are adding the zip to your destination folder.  Then you extract all the files to the same folder so the zip will still be there with the files.  Extract does not delete the zip after extraction.